# Error message in CodeBlocks (IDE for C): "error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" - - I'm a beginner, please help me

Tags: c, ide, codeblocks

I'm a new student at a beginners IT course, the professor ask me to download CodeBlocks and run a simple hello world in C language. He uses another app for Linux or Windows (I'm not sure). But for macOS users he recommended Codeblocks.

So I downloaded it and when I try to build and run, this error message appears. How can I solve this problem?

I think it was supposed to open the terminal and say `"Hello world!"` to me and that is not happening.

### Edit

**Build log:**

```
-------------- Build: Debug in teste (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

gcc -Wall -g  -c "/Users/pamelajacobus/Projects/C/Teste 4/teste/teste4.c" -o obj/Debug/teste4.o
g++  -o bin/Debug/teste obj/Debug/main.o obj/Debug/teste4.o   
duplicate symbol '_main' in:
    obj/Debug/main.o
    obj/Debug/teste4.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

[image]

Comment: In the IDE there's a tab somewhere that shows you the full and complete build log. Please [edit] your question to copy-paste (as text!) the full and complete build log into your question.

Comment: Please add your code along with the error message.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think I did what you asked me to :)

Comment: You build a program with two source files, `main.c` and `teste4.c`. Both these source file have one `main` function each. A program can only have one `main` function (actually, only one of *any* function).